# google maps embedded and permission access

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to dinamically add some simple maps in a page. When I try this static code it works

```
<iframe src="http://maps.google.it/?ie=UTF8&amp;ll=45.442726,12.3925788&amp;t=w&amp;z=12&amp;output=embed&amp;iwloc=near"></iframe>
```

But if I try to add that iframe dinamically with this code

```
var HTMLiframe = document.createElement("iframe");
var code = "src=https://maps.google.it/?ie=UTF8";
code += "&amp;ll=" + itemMap.latitude + "," + itemMap.longitude + "&amp;t=w";
code += "&amp;z" + itemMap.zoom;
code += "&amp;output=embed&amp;iwloc=near";

HTMLiframe.setAttribute("src", code);
HTMLelemFather.appendChild(HTMLiframe);
```

UPDATED:
An error message is logged: Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options
How can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this:

```
var code = "src=https://maps.google.it/?ie=UTF8";
```

Change it to:

```
var code = "https://maps.google.it/?ie=UTF8";
```

this part assigns it to the src attribute of the iframe element:

```
HTMLiframe.setAttribute("src", code);
```

Comment: thanks! But now I get another problem. Nothing is displayed and a message is logged: Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options

Comment: @LorenzoC also change &amp; to & ,then it will be ok :-)

Comment: @LorenzoC I am glad it works finally too! :-) Btw, noticed this difference between submitted URLs in the [LivehttpHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) addon.